# Managed Ubuntu 20.04 system - login loop

Tags: 20.04, login, login-screen

I have been struggling with a login loop issue for ~1 month now and am unable to resolve it despite help from my work IT department. The issue is that I am unable to login through the GUI - if I do, I get sent straight back to the screen where I am asked to choose my user (i.e. a login loop).

What I've tried / discovered so far:

1. If I open a `ttyl` (Ctrl + Alt + F2) I can login there and then do `startx` to get to the desktop environment. This is not ideal as some features are lacking.
2. This problem started when I restored my old laptop backup.
3. I have an Ubuntu system which is managed by my university's IT department, so my user is linked to the IT system.
4. Choosing "Ubuntu" instead of "Ubuntu on Wayland" at login does not help.
5. `sudo sss_cache -E` does not help, even on restart.
6. In `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` I have the line `ad_gpo_access_control = disabled` which should be correct apparently.
7. I ran `sudo puppet agent -t` which apparently should have setup some configuration files properly.
8. I have the correct permissions on my home folder, namely `drwxr-xr-x 67 u0128861 domain users 4096`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In my case, whenever I encounter a "login loop", it is due to configuration files in my home directory in directories that start with `.`.  So, in `~/.gnome`, for example.  So, you are not the administrator of this system?  If you were and you had a lot of time, I would create an account like "abc" and see if you can log in fine with that.  If you can, then that's a user-level (and not a system-level) configuration problem.  Then, I'd copy the directories in my home directory over one by one until I find the offending directory.

Comment: Usually, I lack the patience to do this and just remove all directories in my home directory that have gnome-related configuration files.  I just accept that I have to reset my favourite short-cut keys, etc.  I'd start with creating a new user account (if you can) to see if the problem is with the system or your user account.